# Converting String into org.joda.time.Period

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am using java spring boot and am trying to do a POST call using POSTMAN but the object that I am trying to use is a org.joda.time.Period and it is marked as 'required'. I have been unsuccessful at creating that object. 
I have tried many values, and the following list are just a few of them

```
"rangeStart": "1325965615539L", 
"rangeStart": "P1Y",
"rangeStart": "2017-03-13T15:22:52.812"
```

The message that I get back is

```
{
  "status": 422,
  "code": 0,
  "message": "Invalid TimePeriod format '\"2017-03-13T15:22:52.812\"'.",
  "error": true
}
```

Does anybody know what I should use?

Comment: How do you handle date time input format at back-end?

Comment: I use a SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); and then sdf.parse(o.getString("nextExecutionTime")); where nextExecutionTime is a DateTime

Comment: You need to edit your question and show us your entity and any app config where you might be managing the date format deserialization process. You're likely missing a bit of stuff on both. For example, all my joda time properties in my entities are annotated with `@Type` using a jadira usertype.